# Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, buffer

If I add the following lines into my code it throws the following error:

```
import { BIP32Interface } from "bip32";

let node: BIP32Interface = bip32.fromBase58(key);
```

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
```

I'm using the same package in a Next.js app, so I think the problem here, that I haven't got node.js environment when compiling happens...

How could I pass this issue?

I tried:
yarn add buffer ->

```
window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 49):

Install the browser buffer package:

```
npm install --save buffer
```

Import it and use it directly, example:

```
import {Buffer} from 'buffer';
Buffer.from('anything','base64');
```

Comment: why `--save` is needed?

Comment: It is not. It used to be, it would save the package to you package.json I believe. Now it's automatic

Answer (score 15):

First do this:

```sh
npm install --save buffer
```

Then add

```js
 window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;
```

after my import statements. It worked for me.

Comment: Would you mind adding WHY this works?

Comment: This works as the problem is that window.Buffer is undefined unless defined by some plugin, this sets the buffer to the buffer library that you installed.
For typescript this worked for me:

```import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
if (!window.Buffer) {
  window.Buffer = Buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I got this buffer error when I tried to upload object (doc/pdf/image) etc from react to AWS S3 Bucket. Then after referring multiple website i got the solution below.

Find this sample react code to understand.

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import S3FileUpload from 'react-s3';
window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;

function App() {
  const onFileChange = (file)=>{
    const config = {
      bucketName: 'bucket-name',
      dirName: 'photos', /* optional */
      region: 'us-east-1',
      accessKeyId: 'access-key-id',
      secretAccessKey: 'secret-access-key',
    }
    S3FileUpload.uploadFile(file, config)
    .then((data)=>{
      console.log(data.location);
    }).catch((err)=>{
      alert(err);
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello React</h1>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e)=>onFileChange(e.target.files[0])} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;
Add this statement after all the import statements to get rid of "buffer is not defined"

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error and this is how I solved the problem. But I have no clue as to why.

firs:

```
npm install --save buffer
```

(I don't know what it does, but it worked.) and then;

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

Buffer.from("anything", "base64");
window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;
```

Comment: This worked for me on VUE 3 CLI project

Answer (score 2):

for me what worked was:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import reactfrom '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'path'
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        }
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            plugins: [inject({ Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'] })],
        },
    },
})
```

reply to this comment:

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/2785#discussioncomment-1452855

Answer (score 0):

Install the browser buffer package:

```
npm install --save buffer
```

Then use this in your  component

```
 import { Buffer } from "buffer/"; 
 window.Buffer = Buffer;
```

This worked for me(Vite-Project)

Answer (score 0):

i am using vite + react and can work below

```
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill'
export default defineConfig({
    // ...other config settings
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            // Node.js global to browser globalThis
            define: {
                global: 'globalThis'
            },
            // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
            plugins: [
                NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                    buffer: true
                })
            ]
        }
    }

})
```

in vite.config.ts, check here [Buffer is not defined in React-vite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714690/buffer-is-not-defined-in-react-vite)