# Buffer is not defined in React-vite

Tags: reactjs, buffer, vite

Buffer is not defined after migrating from CRA(create react app)

[image: Screenshot of error]

"vite": "^2.7.12"

I try to add plugins, add define for Buffer, but it's not work.

```
const viteConfig = defineConfig({
/*    define: {
        "Buffer": {}
    },*/
    plugins: [reactRefresh(), react()],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: resolve('index.html'),
            },
        },
    },
    clearScreen: false
});
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Install this library

@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill

and add this in your vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
    // ...other config settings
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            // Node.js global to browser globalThis
            define: {
                global: 'globalThis'
            },
            // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
            plugins: [
                NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                    buffer: true
                })
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

add this libary import to your vite.config.js

```
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill'
```

Comment: i'm using vite.config.ts, how can i stop typescript complaining about missing types for @esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill? couldn't find a @types package. best i've managed is adding //ts-ignore, but not happy about it

Comment: I'm getting this error while running, Invalid define value (must be an entity name or valid JSON syntax)

Comment: This only fixes it in development mode for me

Comment: This one didn't work for me, but `sable`'s answer below did work.

Answer (score 23):

[Николай Сычев solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70719923/4300054) didn't work for me at first.

Instead, I succeeded by simply

1. installing buffer as a dev dependency
   `yarn add buffer` (use npm equivalent if you use npm)
2. and then adding it to the global scope in the index.html like this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="module">
      import { Buffer } from "buffer";
      window.Buffer = Buffer;
    </script>   
   ...
```

It also works for similar dependencies like `process` which you'd import in the index.html like this:

```
      import process from "process";
      window.process = process;
```

---

**Update**

For a different project I needed `util`, which required `process`. The above suggested method didn't suffice in that case.

Instead I found out that `@esbuild-plugins` (for `vite dev`) and `rollup-plugin-polyfill-node` (for `vite build`) would successfully provide all these nodejs packages.

Here is a full `vite.config.ts` that works for me:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill'
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill'
import rollupNodePolyFill from 'rollup-plugin-polyfill-node'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  base: '', 
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      // Node.js global to browser globalThis
      define: {
        global: 'globalThis'
      },
      // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
      plugins: [
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          buffer: true, 
          process: true,
        }), 
        NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin() 
      ]
    }
  }, 
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [
        rollupNodePolyFill()
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Be careful to use `rollup-plugin-polyfill-node` which is an updated and maintained fork of `rollup-plugin-node-polyfills`.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest solution I found was to install `vite-plugin-node-polyfills` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node-polyfills), [repo](https://github.com/davidmyersdev/vite-plugin-node-polyfills)).

`npm i -D vite-plugin-node-polyfills`

Below is a basic version of the config file, `vite.config.js`, using this plugin:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [nodePolyfills()]
})
```

---

The current accepted answer recommends `@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill`, which is outdated according to its [repository](https://github.com/remorses/esbuild-plugins), while the replacement suggested there, `esbuild-plugin-polyfill-node`, doesn't work for vite (see issue [here](https://github.com/cyco130/esbuild-plugin-polyfill-node/issues/13)).

Comment: This worked for me in vite 4. Thanks man!

Comment: Worked for me too with Vite 4, thanks!

Comment: Also worked for me with vite + vue 3, thank you!

Comment: this work only in DEV mode?

Comment: @LuisFelipeGongoraGarcia By default this adds polyfills in all modes. See the plugin npm or repo link for its options.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the detailed analysis of alternative packages! Works in vite 5.0

Answer (score 6):

For me the above configuration did not work, I had to make changes in 3 files ,
in vite.config.ts , index.html and adding packages

**1.Install Packages**

```
yarn install process util buffer events
yarn add @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill
```

**2.Update vite.config**

```
import GlobalPolyFill from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            define: {
                global: "globalThis",
            },
            plugins: [
                GlobalPolyFill({
                    process: true,
                    buffer: true,
                }),
            ],
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            process: "process/browser",
            stream: "stream-browserify",
            zlib: "browserify-zlib",
            util: "util",
        },
    },
});
```

**3.Update index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/src/assets/images/favicon.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Vite App</title>
  <script>
    window.global = window;
  </script>
  <script type="module">
    import process from "process";
    import EventEmitter from "events";
    import {Buffer} from "buffer";
    window.Buffer = Buffer;
    window.process = process;
    window.EventEmitter = EventEmitter;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="module" src="./src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are some errors in which packages to use in the installation process and furthermore in their usage.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without importing in via script? I want to build it as a js file.

Comment: I am not aware of it sorry

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is:

```
npm i -D rollup-plugin-polyfill-node
```

Then update `vite.config.ts` with the following:

```
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-polyfill-node'
```

```
rollupOptions: {
  plugins: [
    // ...plugins
    nodePolyfills(),
  ],
  // ...rollupOptions
},
```

Comment: This caused me to have other issues when trying to import items from react such as `useLayoutEffect`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using vite (4.2.1) and near-api-js (2.1.0).
I stumbled upon this [github thread](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/issues/1072#issuecomment-1452468681), which contained these [vite config settings](https://github.com/kujtimprenkuSQA/near-api-js-vue/blob/add-polyfills-in-another-way/vite.config.js)

In order to make the near api work for my project, I added these settings to `vite.config.ts`:

```ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
// added below polyfills to make near-api-js work with vite
// npm install --dev @esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill';
// npm install --dev @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill';

fs.rmSync('dist', { recursive: true, force: true }); // v14.14.0

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [],
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: [],
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    disabled: false,
    esbuildOptions: {
      // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
      plugins: [
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          process: true,
          buffer: true,
        }),
        NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that worked for me when migrating from CRA to Vite, is to use a [browser library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) for `buffer` support (instead of relying on a Node polyfill):

```bash
npm i buffer
```

```js
import {Buffer} from 'buffer';
...
Buffer.from(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to vite.config.ts

```
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject'

export default defineConfig({
.......
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        plugins: [
          inject({ Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'] })]
      }
    }
})
```

In addition, you need to

```
npm install --save  buffer
```

You can use it by

```
const encodedString = Buffer.from(myString).toString('base64');
```

The `import { Buffer } from 'buffer'` command is no needed