# Replacing zlib as part of migration to Vite/Vue3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite

I've inherited a Vue 2 application that we are in the process of upgrading to Vue 3, which involves moving to Vite. My biggest hang-up is trying to replicate some compression/decompression logic.

The basic use case is that we want to either compress or decompress some audio before sending it to the server (or when getting it back from the server) inside the client browser. Here's the code in question:

```
import * as zlib from 'zlib'

function b64CompressedToObject(src) {
  return JSON.parse(zlib.unzipSync(Buffer.from(src, 'base64')).toString('utf-8'))
}

function b64CompressedToString(src) {
  return zlib.unzipSync(Buffer.from(src, 'base64')).toString('utf-8').replaceAll('"', '')
}

function compressAndB64Encode(src) {
  return zlib.gzipSync(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(src))).toString('base64')
}
```

I'm trying to avoid, if at all possible, adding a bunch of pollyfills and other workarounds as described in some of the [related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714690/buffer-is-not-defined-in-react-vite). Is there a better way to go about this if I'm willing to rewrite this portion (or potentially more) of the code?