# Error when working on a Typescript RPC library in Vue but works in React

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on a typescript RPC library in Vite/Vue 3. The library I am trying to work on is as follows:

`"verusd-rpc-ts-client": "git+https://github.com/VerusCoin/verusd-rpc-ts-client.git",`

I am getting the following error:

```
Module "util" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "util.debuglog" in client code. See http://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.
get @ verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:4935
Show 1 more frame
Show less
verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:4935 Module "util" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "util.inspect" in client code. See http://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.
get @ verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:4935
Show 1 more frame
Show less
verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:9155 Module "stream" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "stream.Transform" in client code. See http://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.
get @ verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:9155
Show 1 more frame
Show less
verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:9292 Module "buffer" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "buffer.Buffer" in client code. See http://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.
get @ verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:9292
Show 1 more frame
Show less
verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:12567 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/constants/vdxf.js (verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:12567:63)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=63353c53:3:50)
    at node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/vdxf/index.js (verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:13773:18)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=63353c53:3:50)
    at node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/vdxf/classes/Challenge.js (verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:14025:15)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=63353c53:3:50)
    at node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/vdxf/classes/index.js (verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:15656:23)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=63353c53:3:50)
    at node_modules/verus-typescript-primitives/dist/index.js (verusd-rpc-ts-client.js?v=63353c53:16165:18)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=63353c53:3:50)
```

Now the error could be related to the library itself but the same library works fine in Vue JS. I can make direct rpc calls from the URL but want to use the library directly so any changes made to the library could be integrated in my code by simply making it as a submodule.

My code is JS:

```
proxyRPC:

// proxyVerusd.js
import { VerusdRpcInterface } from 'verusd-rpc-ts-client'

const verusd = VerusdRpcInterface("iJhCezBExJHvtyH3fGhNnt2NhU4Ztkf2yq", "https://api.verustest.net");

export const fetchConversion = async () => {
  const res = await verusd.getCurrency('bridge.veth')
  const info = await verusd.getInfo()

  const block = info.result.longestchain

  const bestState = res.result.bestcurrencystate
  const currencyNames = res.result.currencynames
  const currencies = bestState.reservecurrencies
  const count = currencies.length
  const { supply } = bestState
  const daiKey = Object.keys(res?.result?.currencynames).find((key) => currencyNames !== undefined && currencyNames[key] === 'DAI.vETH')
  const daiAmount = currencies.find(c => c.currencyid === daiKey).reserves

  let list = currencies.map((token) => ({ name: currencyNames[token.currencyid], amount: token.reserves, daiPrice: daiAmount / token.reserves }))
  const bridge = { name: 'Bridge.vETH', amount: supply, daiPrice: (daiAmount * count) / supply }

  let conversions = [
    { symbol: 'vrsc', price: 0 },
    { symbol: 'eth', price: 0 },
    { symbol: 'mkr', price: 0 },
    { symbol: 'dai', price: 0 }
  ]

  try {
    conversions = await Promise.all(
      urls.map(async (url) => fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((c) => ({
          symbol: c.symbol,
          price: c.market_data.current_price.usd
        })))
    )
  } catch (error) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.error('%s: fetching prices %s', Date().toString(), error)
  }
  list = list.map((token) => {
    switch (token.name) {
      case 'VRSCTEST':
      case 'VRSC':
        return {
          ...token,
          price:
            conversions.find((c) => c.symbol === 'vrsc')?.price
        }
      case 'vETH':
        return {
          ...token,
          price: conversions.find((c) => c.symbol === 'eth')?.price
        }
      case 'DAI.vETH':
        return {
          ...token,
          price: 1
        }
      case 'MKR.vETH':
        return {
          ...token,
          price: conversions.find((c) => c.symbol === 'mkr')?.price
        }
      // return { ...token, price: vrscPrice }
      default:
        return { ...token }
    }
  })
  return { list, bridge, currencies }
}

export const fetchCurrency = async (currency) => {
  try {
    const response = await verusd.getCurrency(currency);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching currency:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const fetchInfo = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await verusd.getInfo();
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching info:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

// You can add more proxy methods here if needed
```

I use the code above in my Vue component as follows:

```
<script>
import { fetchInfo, fetchConversion } from "./utils/proxyGet"; 

export default {
  name: 'VerusCurrencies',
  async mounted() {
    await this.getConsole();
  },
  methods: {
    async getConsole() {
      try {
        //const res = await fetchCurrency("Bridge.vEth");
        const info = await fetchInfo();
        const getCon = await fetchConversion();
 
        //console.log(res);
        console.log(info);
        console.log(getCon);
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle errors if needed
        console.log("Cannot get data")
      }
    },
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: This is specific to a bundler (Vite), not relevant to Vue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714690/buffer-is-not-defined-in-react-vite

Comment: You are  life saver thank you