# Use bitcoinjs-lib Uncaught TypeErrorCannot read properties of undefined (reading 'alloc')

Tags: javascript, bitcoinjs-lib

Vite & React
In js

```
import * as bitcoin from 'bitcoinjs-lib';
```

but something wrong :

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'alloc')
at node_modules/bitcoinjs-lib/src/types.js (bitcoinjs-lib.js?v=cf991875:920:34)
    at __require (chunk-Y2F7D3TJ.js?v=e728907c:3:50)
    at node_modules/bitcoinjs-lib/src/script_signature.js (bitcoinjs-lib.js?v=cf991875:1030:17)
    at __require (chunk-Y2F7D3TJ.js?v=e728907c:3:50)
    at node_modules/bitcoinjs-lib/src/script.js (bitcoinjs-lib.js?v=cf991875:1101:27)
    at __require (chunk-Y2F7D3TJ.js?v=e728907c:3:50)
    at node_modules/bitcoinjs-lib/src/payments/embed.js (bitcoinjs-lib.js?v=cf991875:1312:19)
    at __require (chunk-Y2F7D3TJ.js?v=e728907c:3:50)
    at node_modules/bitcoinjs-lib/src/payments/index.js (bitcoinjs-lib.js?v=cf991875:4800:19)
    at __require (chunk-Y2F7D3TJ.js?v=e728907c:3:50)
```

screenshot： https://imgse.com/i/pi7KPOJ

package.json

```
`"bip32": "^4.0.0",
"bitcoinjs-lib": "^6.1.5",
"ecpair": "^2.1.0",`
```

I would be grateful for any help!

How to use bitcoinjs-lib?

Answer (score 0):

what is alloc,
Need more clarification share your code.

here example :

```
import { BIP32Factory } from 'bip32';
import * as bitcoin from 'bitcoinjs-lib';

const mainnet = bitcoin.networks.bitcoin;
bitcoin.initEccLib(ecc);
const bip32 = BIP32Factory(ecc);
```

More in [official documentation](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib)

Answer (score 0):

Need

```
yarn add Buffer
```

vite.config.js node built-in polyfills

```
    // yarn add --dev @esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill
    import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill'
    // yarn add --dev @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill
    import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill'

...
    optimizeDeps: {
            esbuildOptions: {
                // Node.js global to browser globalThis
                define: {
                    global: 'globalThis'
                },
                // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
                plugins: [
                    NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                        process: true,
                        buffer: true
                    }),
                    NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin()
                ]
            }
        }
```

Reference:

[Buffer is not defined in React-vite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714690/buffer-is-not-defined-in-react-vite)

https://gist.github.com/FbN/0e651105937c8000f10fefdf9ec9af3d