# Drizzle ORM + Vite-react - Postgres.js TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Socket')

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, vite, drizzle, drizzle-orm

I'm using Drizzle ORM on my vite-react web app and running into a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Socket')` error. I'm spinning up postgres from docker and can confirm the db connection is correct because `db:push` works with my drizzle-orm schema. I'm just trying to create a simple aysnc component to test everything together but keep getting the `Socket` error. I've tried about everything here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714690/buffer-is-not-defined-in-react-vite` which fixed the `buffer` issue but not the `Socket` issue. Any help would be appreciated.

`schema.js`

```
import { pgTable, serial, varchar } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";

export const testing = pgTable("testing", {
  id: serial("id").notNull().primaryKey(),
  name: varchar("name", { length: 256 }),
});
```

`index.js`

```
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/postgres-js";
import postgres from "postgres";
import * as schema from "./schema";

// DB connection
const queryClient = postgres(import.meta.env.VITE_DB_CONNECTION_STRING);
const db = drizzle(queryClient, { schema });

export { db };
```

`vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import { nodePolyfills } from "vite-plugin-node-polyfills";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [nodePolyfills(), react()],
});
```

`testingDB.jsx`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db } from "../../db";

export default function TestingDb() {
  const [testing, setTesting] = useState(null); 

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTesting = async () => {
      const result = await db.query.testing.findFirst();
      setTesting(result);
    };
    fetchTesting();
  }, []); 

  return (
    <div>
      {testing ? (
        <div key={testing.id}>{testing.name}</div> 
      ) : (
        <p>No data found</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're trying to establish a database connection from frontend code, which is very doubtful by itself already, but is probably also the reason for your error. I guess the browser won't let you pass -- does it work as intended from backend code?

Comment: That's what's intended from Drizzle ORM as it relates to the code. And I know there is a connection and it works because `drizzle-kit push:pg --config=drizzle.config.js` works just fine. It's when I try to read from the db where the issue arises.

Comment: Yes, but you run `drizzle-kit` from your command-line, so you're not going via the browser in that case. Drizzle is not designed to be used on client side from a browser; would you mind sharing the docs that made you think you should use it this way?

Comment: @jbndlr Sure, here's where I saw the documentation. Documentation > Access your data > query. https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/rqb#:~:text=Discord-,Drizzle%20Queries,-Drizzle%20ORM%20is

Comment: Well, what you see there is actually TypeScript backend code. There's no JSX or other frontend stuff involved. You'll need an API layer that does the database queries and provides an interface to your frontend (e.g. REST, tRPC, GraphQL).

Comment: @jbndlr I can't get something like this in a  `queries.js` file to work either:  
```import { db } from ".";
export const getTesting = async () => {
  const data = await db.query.testing.findMany();
  return data;
};```