# Base45 - Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base45

Good day. I have app created via create-react-app and I am trying to create decoder for covid greenpass. I have an issue with base45 decoding. It causes error like this:

```
base45-js.js:60 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at Object.decode (base45-js.js:60:1)
    at CovidPass (CovidPass.js:10:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
```

Here's code. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
import React from 'react';
import cbor from 'cbor-web';
import base45 from 'base45';
import pako from 'pako';   

const CovidPass = () => {
    const decodedBase45 = base45.decode('I2B-KEP2');
    console.log(decodedBase45);

    return (
        <p>{decodedBase45}</p>
    );
}

export default CovidPass;
```

Answer (score 4):

**This is from an old answer here:**

Install the browser buffer package:

```
npm install --save buffer
```

Import it and use it directly, example:

```
import {Buffer} from 'buffer';
Buffer.from('anything','base64');
```

ref:
[Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804053/uncaught-referenceerror-buffer-is-not-defined-in-react)

Comment: Doesnt work with base45 encoding. Any tip how to use it with my code?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by downgrading `"react-scripts": "5.0.0"` to `"react-scripts": "4.0.3"` in `package.json`, and running `npm install`. But I think there's much better solution.